# How can I see how dune is invoking the ocaml compiler?

Tags: ocaml, dune

I'd like to reproduce some of dune's functionality in buck2, but have no idea how to implement dune's functionality where [a wrapped module can specify a library interface](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dune-files.html#library).

I'd like to see how dune is invoking ocaml tools such as ocamlopt.opt, to see what flags are passed. In buck2 this can be done with [`buck2 what-ran`](https://buck2.build/docs/developers/what-ran/), does dune have something similar?

If not, where can I stick a `Printf.printf` in the dune source to see how it's invoking other tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be looking for the `--display` option with a value of `verbose`.

```
dune exec --display=verbose
```